# Asynchronous drag (and drop) from UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, asynchronous, winapi, uwp

I'm trying to implement drag & drop mechanism in my UWP app, so that items from my app could be easily copied into other apps.

The problem is that I don't always have the data which should be copied, at the moment when the drag operation starts. Instead, I wait for an async operation to finish, and only then update the deferral's data.

That's the code I've been using, basically:

```
private void myGrid_DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
    args.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;

    someAsyncFunction(async (data) => // this callback might take a few seconds to be invoked
    {
            // 
            // ... some code which also invokes another function with "await"
            //

            args.Data.SetStorageItems(new[] { data });
            deferral.Complete();
    });
}
```

As a result, when the user starts dragging an item from my app into another app, it will **have a  sign next to the mouse cursor**. Also, and much worse than that, if the user releases the mouse button (while dragging it) before I got the data for the drag deferral, **then nothing will happen** (as if the operation silently failed).

I already thought about giving some indication to the user on my own app, about when the data is ready so they can release the mouse button. But is there any better way to prevent either of these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

For you scenario, I assume that you have two Grid to implement the whole "Drag and Drop" operation process. One Grid is source control and another is target.

You said '**if the user releases the mouse button (while dragging it) before I got the data for the drag deferral, then nothing will happen (as if the operation silently failed).**'

To handle this scenario, you could register the DropCompleted event and tell the user 'DropResult'.

I made a simple code sample for you to understand the whole process.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid CanDrag="True" Width="100" Height="100" Background="AliceBlue" DragStarting="Grid_DragStarting" DropCompleted="Grid_DropCompleted">

    </Grid>
    <Grid AllowDrop="True" Width="200" Height="200" Background="LightBlue" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Drop="Grid_Drop" DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" DragOver="Grid_DragOver" DragLeave="Grid_DragLeave">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Grid_DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DragStarting");
        var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
        args.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;

        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
         {
             await Task.Delay(10000);
             StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"));
             args.Data.SetStorageItems(new[] { file });
             deferral.Complete();
         });

    }

    private void Grid_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DragLeave");
    }

    private void Grid_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DragEnter");
    }

    private void Grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DragOver");
        if (!e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "There're no StorageItems!";
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.None;
        }
        else
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        }
    }

    private async void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Drop");
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                var storageFile = items[0] as StorageFile;
                Debug.WriteLine(storageFile.DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Grid_DropCompleted(UIElement sender, DropCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DropCompleted");
        Debug.WriteLine(args.DropResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, but what I'm looking for is not to drag and drop between two grids within my own app, but from my app into any other app that can accept binary data as a drag into (for example, even Windows' own file explorer)